# Did they ever find a fancontrol solution for Toshibas?

Tags: overheating, fan, toshiba

Overheating is a real problem to the point where my Toshiba Satellite automatically shuts down after exceeding 85dg C. I'm not knowledgeable with linux/ubuntu in the least so if I am missing any other data, sorry.

I've looked everywhere and tried every solution but the one sensor module in my Toshiba Satellite, coretemp is not pwm-capable when I try "pwmconfig". The only thing that comes up in "sensors-detect" is coretemp and the line was added to /etc/modules.

Many thanks in advance.